# Styled Component prop inside a map

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to calculate the svg width based on a prop value.
It's an array of svg and each one should have a specific width.
It is perfectly calculating the width value but it's repeating the first value of the map for all others.
When I console.log the value inside the map it shows different values for each one.

> Here's the map:

```
  {example.map(v => (
              <ComponentExample value={v.value} />
   ))}
```

> Here's the styled component receiving prop:

```
const ComponentExample = styled(ExampleSVG)<{ value: number; }>`
width: ${props => (props.value * 100) / 5}%;`;
```

Comment: I don't there's enough here to meet the *reproducible* portion of a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you provide a more comprehensive code example? If you're able to also provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and live debug in that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/styled-components-typescript-map-jnqnkc) and I couldn't.

```
 {widths.map((value) => (
    <Box key={`key-${value}`} value={value}>
      Hi! I'm a box with {(value * 100) / 5}% width.
    </Box>
  ))}
```

- don't forget to add the `key` on the component in the map.
- if your values are bigger than 5, then you will have values bigger than 100% for width, maybe use rem, px instead of %